# full matrix compare of two dataframes cell by cell

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two different dataframe, I'm currently comparing them using iterrows in the following code:

```
    for idx, row in elf_df.iterrows():
        address_df_idx = 0
        while address_df_idx < address_df_idx_max and not address_df.loc[address_df_idx, 'start_address_int'] <= row.start_address_int <= address_df.loc[address_df_idx, 'end_address_int']:
                address_df_idx += 1

        if address_df_idx < address_df_idx_max:
            address_df.loc[address_df_idx, 'entry_size'] -= int(row['size'], 16)

    row = address_df.loc[address_df['entry_size'].idxmax()]
```

The dataframe's have different sizes, elf_df has 5 entries, and address_df has 3 entries. and I need to perform the following check for each address_df entry with all of the elf_df entries.

Is there a better way to do this then using iterrows?

Comment: that is a pretty torturous route.  Is there a compelling reason that you are trying to do this within `pandas`?  Can it be done before putting the info into data frames or just avoid pandas altogether?

Comment: The entire system uses pandas and those DF's comes from CSV files that are created in an earlier time.. those constraints are forcing me to use pandas..